# Mail "received" header change

Tags: php

It has been 2 days now trying to find a solution for this problem.

Recently my local ISP changed their security settings and now emails generate from PHP scripts is being rejected due header "Received: (from apache@localhost)".

Searching various articles and forums I have come to know that webserver/computer cannot find its own name (so it comes out
as "localhost") when mails are being sent. I have every solution mentioned on the forums but still could not change the "localhost" part to my server name.

1. hostname at /etc/hosts is ok.
2. have added MASQUERADE_AS... to /etc/mail/sendmail.mc...
3. /etc/sysconfig/network is ok.

I desparately need help and wonder if someone can help me solve this problem.

```
function MAIL_NVLP($fromname, $fromaddress, $toname, $toaddress, $subject, $message)
{
    // Copyright ? 2005 ECRIA LLC, http://www.ECRIA.com
    // Please use or modify for any purpose but leave this notice unchanged.
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$fromname."\" <".$fromaddress.">\n";
    return mail($toaddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

$message = "This is a test from the support dept";
$fromname = "myname";
$fromaddress = "myname@domain.com";
$toname = "myname";
$toaddress = "myname@domain.com";
$subject = "testing new script one";
MAIL_NVLP($fromname, $fromaddress, $toname, $toaddress, $subject, $message);

echo $subject;
```

Comment: Do you get this same issue when you change `mail($toaddress, $subject, $message, $headers);` to `mail($toaddress, $subject, $message, $headers, "-fFROM@ADDRESS.COM");`

Comment: your ISP is also your web host?